# Kendo UI Grid, server filtering and sorting

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an application with `kendo UI Grid` used with `Angular`. I enabled `serverfiltering` and `serversorting`.

My Backend has, WebAPI, custom Business Logic with `entity framework`. I use `ViewModels/DTOs` to bind data to my kendo grid, but when kendo grid is sorted or filtered, I need to filter on the EF by mapping the fields.

I tried searching online to see a similar concept, but most of them use `oData` which does not suit my requirement. I tried writing my own code to extend `LINQ` to sort or filter on the fields, but I run into issues with child/parent entities and a few more issues.

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: By using Telerik UI for mvc, you can use WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder. See an exaple: [link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/binding/web-api-server-operations)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I used SimplePaginate. Hope this might help you.

[SimplePaginate Github](https://github.com/RiponDatta/SimplePaginate)

```
var filters = new Filters<Employee>(); 
filters.Add(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText), x => x.LoginID.Contains(searchText));
filters.Add(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobTitle), x => x.JobTitle.Equals(jobTitle));

var sorts = new Sorts<Employee>();
sorts.Add(sortBy == 1, x => x.BusinessEntityID);
sorts.Add(sortBy == 2, x => x.LoginID, true); 
sorts.Add(sortBy == 3, x => x.JobTitle);

context.Employees.Paginate(currentPage, pageSize, sorts, filters);
```

[NuGet Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimplePaginate)